# What are the requirements for a sound file in android?

Tags: android, sound

I am creating a game in Android and eventually I am going to outsource the sound effects. I have a few place holder sounds for testing and I have noticed a problem.  I have an OGG sound file which plays correctly through the emulator/headphones but when I put it on my phone it doesn't play.  Putting my ear right up to the speaker I can hear a faint crackle.

So what are the requirements for a mobile sound file?  Frequency, format, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `android.media.SoundPool` or another library?

Core Media Supported formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Peter Drescher on implementing sound in Android games via FMOD:
http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2011/06/fmod-for-android.html
http://www.twittering.com/

He also did a presentation at the most recent AES convention in NY where he showed the equivalent implementation of FMOD vs Android for the Vector Pinball game, I don't know if he put his slides online though, can't find them anywhere.

Ogg vorbis should work fine though. Make sure you start with one encoded and formatted as a basic stereo or mono 44.1kHz Ogg Vorbis file.

Comment: Using android.media.mediaplayer   Thanks for this info